# How can I retrieve the values of a variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I want to know how can I get the values of this code:

```
<input type="radio" name="pgto" value="entry1" class="payment" />

jQuery(".payment").click(function(e){
   alert(e);
}
```

when I click in payment radio, the alert msg says [object object],
I try to search how can I get the values of the 'e' variable function,
I found this 'e.currentTarget' current Target, if I do something like e.currentTarget.value it will 
alert de value entry1 if I do e.currentTarget.name it will alert 'pgto'.

What I want to know is what are the options for object variable 'e'.

I know that there is the currentTarget option. What are the others???
Like: 
alert(e.something);

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much point in duplicating the API documentation. Just RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Just print it `console.log(e)`.

Answer (score -1):

if you run this with firebug then you can see all the properties of e:

```
jQuery(".payment").click(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

1. You are grabbing every single element on the page that has the class `payment`. This might give you inputs, or divs, etc. You want that exact `<input>`, place a id on it.
2. You are attempting to alert the `event-object` as @Quentin has pointed out, read his comment
3. If you want to get the value of a input like this, you're going to have to write: `$(*get input*).val()`
4. If you wanted to test the printing out of an object, `alert()` is not the function to use. Try `console.log( *object* )`

Comment: console.log(e); help a lot! show all options! Thanks!